# Does SQL lock tables when queries return results greater than 5000 records?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I'm am working in SharePoint and am trying to understand why there is a limit of 5000 records for views on lists that can have a far greater number.

My question is not about SharePoint, but SQL.  Does SQL have the limit described below, or was this something imposed on SQL by the SharePoint team?

> For performance reasons, whenever SQL Server executes a single query
>   that returns 5000 + items, locks escalation happens within the SQL
>   table. As a result, the entire table will be locked. Since the entire
>   Share Point data is stored as a single table, a single list view query
>   that exceeds 5000+ items will lock the entire Share Point data table
>   within that content. The database and all the users will face huge
>   performance degradation. The entire set of users using Share Point at
>   the time of lock escalation will have to wait for a longer time to
>   retrieve the data. Hence, you can see that the list threshold is a
>   limitation that is imposed upon Share Point by its backend SQL Server.
>   This issue is generated from SQL and the reason is row lock
>   escalation. In order to avoid this performance degradation, Share
>   Point has imposed the limitation of 5000 items to be queried at any
>   point of time. Any queries for 5000+ items will be dealt the threshold
>   error message. Ref link

Thanks

EDIT____________________________________

An article on this issue:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-list-threshold-issue-the-traditional-problem/

Comment: Hi for my research it's a Sharepoint limitation and doesn't is a sql server limitation see this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/previous-versions/office/mt493258(v=office.16)

Comment: It might help if you linked to where that quote came from (for attribution reasons if no others). So far as I'm aware, the *specific* breakpoint numbers aren't documented by MS.

Comment: Other link can help you : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry... the reference link at the end broke.  Will fix.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon i think a other blog can explain https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/

Comment: @MartinMuldoon please provide some other information : SQL server version; Sharepoint version (or online ?) thanks in advance

Comment: @pascalsanchez just added a link to a post that indicates this applies to all SharePoint versions.  Thanks

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry for the delay.  Just added the link

Comment: That's not a SQL Server limitation. And no, the table won't be locked for just 5000 records. I'd suggest checking Microsoft's documentation or MVP articles instead. That article .... nope. Far too many mistakes and incorrect information. Can you imagine a data warehouse fact table with millions of rows locking up if someone searched a single day's sales?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I totally get what you are saying.  Why would the SharePoint team do this?  Is there something different about querying SQL and presenting the data in a SharePoint list?

Comment: The limit is a *SharePoint* limit. SharePoint isn't a database, it's a document management system. Lists and libaries aren't tables. Views aren't database views.If you check those table you'll see that there are no list-specific tables. All items are stored in the same table that has multiple fields, one per base field type. List items are "shredded" and stored in these tables. As a result, *reconstituting* them is an expensive operation. Querying results in full scans unless some fields are indexed. Since there are no table fields, this means *extracting* the values to another table....

Comment: Long story short, too wide a query will result in large scans that will seriously degrade the performance of a multi-user DMS. End users can't possibly view 5000 items either, unless someone tried to use a List as if it were a table. Specifying proper indexes is critical in this case

Comment: As for why all this? That article is 197% wrong. might as well forget it. SharePoint used the same storage engine as Exchange back in 2001. There were no good document databases back then and Exchange offered an extensible schema. When they moved to SQL Server for scalability reasons in 2003 they emulated that storage. Unfortunately, SharePoint **exploded** in popularity in 2007 which made migrating to a completely new schema if not database almost impossible. Imagine migrating 1M or 5M documents. The team is optimizing the database since, but the use case still requires a document DB

Comment: And that, means that it will always be very difficult to migrate on-premises SharePoint installations. Migrating SharePoint *Online* on the other hand will be invisible to the end users. For all we know they may already be using Azure Blob storage for documents and Azure Table for list fields, with an eye to migrating to CosmosDb

Comment: SQL Server may attempt lock escalation after 5,000 locks are held on a single object reference. See [Escalation Threshold for a Transact-SQL Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms184286(v=sql.105)) But unless running at a higher than usual isolation level this won't be after 5,000 items are read. You would need both row locking and at least repeatable read for items and locks to be correlated like that. At read committed locks are released as soon as the data is read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does SQL Server lock tables when queries return results greater than 5000
>   records?

Not generally, no.

It [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms184286(v=sql.105)) that 5,000 is a magic number for the database engine to first attempt lock escalation (followed by further attempts at 1,250 increments) but unless running at repeatable read or serializable isolation level this will not generally be hit just by returning 5,0000 items in a `SELECT`. The default read committed level will release locks as soon as the data is read so never hit the threshold.

You can see the effect of isolation level on this with the following example.

```
CREATE TABLE T(C INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO T 
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
FROM sys.all_objects o1, sys.all_objects o2
```

And (uses undocumented trace flags so should only be used in dev environment)

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604,611);

/*5,000 key locks are held*/
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 5000  C FROM T) T
SELECT resource_type, request_mode, count(*) FROM sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id = @@spid GROUP BY resource_type, request_mode;
COMMIT


/*No key locks are held. They have been escalated to an object level lock. The messages tab shows the lock escalation (in my case after 6248 locks not 5,000)*/
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 10000  C FROM T) T
SELECT resource_type, request_mode, count(*) FROM sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id = @@spid GROUP BY resource_type, request_mode;
COMMIT


/*No key locks are held. They are released straight away at this isolation level. The messages tab shows no lock escalation messages*/
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 10000  C FROM T) T
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id = @@spid 
COMMIT


DBCC TRACEOFF(3604,611);
```